# How to compare two column values and update a flag in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here I have a table which contains sales data. Here you can see the Qty,Sell prince and total sale values. Here what I want to achieve is if the Qty is a negative value and total sale value is negative I want to put "Return" in status column other wise the value in the status column is "Sales".
Please help.

```
PartName InvoiceNumber Qty SellPrice TotalSaleValue Status
Part001  INV001        1   1000      1000            Sales
Part002  INV002        5   1500      7500            Sales
Part003  INV003        4   600       2400            Sales
Part001  INV004        2   1000      2000            Sales
Part001  INV001       -1   1000     -1000            Return
Part004  INV005        4   400       1600            Return
Part004  INV005       -4   400      -1600            Return
```

Comment: Suppose part 1 had quantity/sale rows containing 1,1000 1,-1000 1,1000 how would you know that rows 1 and 2 should be return and row 2 should be sale is there some way of relating a return  to a sale in addition to partnumber,quantity and partvalue?

Comment: The scenario is if part is repeating with same quantity and with partvalue is negative I need to flag both as return because 1000-1000 =0 no income comes in

Comment: What if the negative value is not the same?

Comment: SQL stores data as unordered sets there is no guarantee that the order in which you enter data is the order in which it is returned so there is no guarantee that -1000 will follow 1000. Do you have some (unpublished) way of understanding the sequence of events - such as an identity column or timestamp?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It includes tips like providing usable data, not pictures of data, and showing what you've tried.

Comment: Please review my question I made some improvements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4dc0ab2d766a39fe6b70907c598b38ed)

This will update the `Status` when this query is run, how to do this on regularly is left to be answered.

```
UPDATE p1
SET Status=CASE WHEN x.s <=0 THEN 'Return' ELSE 'Sale' END
FROM parts p1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(p2.Partvalue)  as s
                      FROM parts p2 
                      WHERE p2.Partnumber = p1.Partnumber
                      GROUP BY p2.Partnumber) x 
;
```